How to run Typescript code with npm packages in Unity?
I want to run my ts file which uses a npm package in Unity. Is there any way to do that?
Also required tsconfig compiler settings:
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2020",
        "module": "es2022",
        "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
        "outDir": "./build",
        "rootDir": ".",
        "strict": true,
        "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    },
    "include": ["./src"]
}


Nitpick: You can't run TypeScript code. AFAIK, there is no TypeScript runtime environment. You can only transpile the TypeScript code and run the JavaScript code.

by run, if you mean via the cli and only a single file, then use the tsx package and run (npx | yarn | pnpm) tsx <path-to-file>.ts
it's like ts-node but infinitely better
GitHub Repository
if you mean an entire repo in the browser then use tsup to output a dist directory which can then be spun up using node ./dist/index.js. Be sure to set the --dts flag or the field if using a tsup.config.ts file.
those are the two options I can suggest given the somewhat limited context provided in your question
